# OnIncomingError of HubPipelineModule not tiggered

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

In a SignalR project I have the following in order to log exceptions:

`HubExceptionHandler.cs`:

```
public class HubExceptionHandler : HubPipelineModule
{
    protected override void OnIncomingError(ExceptionContext exceptionContext, IHubIncomingInvokerContext invokerContext)
    {
        Panic.EmailIt(exceptionContext.Error, "Exception in hub");
        base.OnIncomingError(exceptionContext, invokerContext);
    }

}
```

`Startup.cs`:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);

        GlobalHost.HubPipeline.AddModule(new HubExceptionHandler());

        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(
        typeof(MonitoringHub),
        () => new MonitoringHub(new DashboardService()));            

        app.MapSignalR();
    }
```

In one of the hub's function all I do is throw an exception:

```
public void AddDecisionServiceApiLog()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
```

The code in the Hub pipeline Module never gets hit. When the exception is thrown all I get is an empty response on the client.

I tried overriding the `BuildIncoming` function in the `HubExceptionHandler.cs` and it works fine so I know the module is being registered successfully.

My guess is that there is something handling the exception somewhere else?

Any ideas?

Comment: hey Jason, any idea how this was solved ?

Comment: @Clint Oh wow sorry too long ago, can't remember at all and left the company I was doing that for so no access to that code any more

Answer (score 0):

If your application is an OWIN application, you need to register the HubPipelineModule in a different way.

[This link is from the Autofac documentation, but shows an example of how to register it properly.](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/signalr.html#owin-integration)

```
public class Startup
{
  public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
  {
     // Get your HubConfiguration. In OWIN, you'll create one
     // rather than using GlobalHost.
     var config = new HubConfiguration();

     app.MapSignalR("/signalr", config);

     // To add custom HubPipeline modules, you have to get the HubPipeline
     // from the dependency resolver, for example:
     var hubPipeline = config.Resolver.Resolve<IHubPipeline>();
     hubPipeline.AddModule(new MyPipelineModule());
  }
}
```